# Unix Create Directories Based on File name and Move Files to the Directories

Tags: unix

I'm trying to write a Unix script to create directories based on file names and move those files to the designated directories.

File pattern:
*PLAIN***nn**.pdf (e.g. 4520009455604706_PLAIN_12**21**.pdf)

Directories to be created: Cy**nn** (e.g. Cy**21**) 
[**NOTE**: Need a step to check if directory exists, if not, then create new directory]

After creating the above directories, I need to move all files matching *PLAIN***21**.pdf to the directory /Cy21.

[EDITED] Solution added below.

Comment: The script you posted works fine on my box.  The error implies that the code you posted here is not the same as what your tried to run.  Are you sure it is the same code?

Comment: Yes, I even tried a simple for loop but still getting the same error. I'm using ksh shell to execute the script with this command: `sh test.sh`.

Comment: sh and ksh are not the same thing.  Are you sure /bin/sh is ksh?

Comment: Even if I try to execute the following script using `ksh test.ksh` command, it returns the same error.
`#!/bin/ksh
for file in *
do
  if test -s $file
  then
    echo $file
  else
        echo "Not"
  fi
done`

Comment: I've identified the issue. It's caused by the incorrect EOL character. I converted it to UNIX/Linux format in Notepad++ and it solved the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in *.pdf
do
  if test -s $file
  then
    cycle=`echo $file | awk -F'.' '{print $1}' | awk '{print substr($0,(length($0)-1))}'`
dir="./Cy"$cycle
if [ -d $dir ]
then
    mv $file ./Cy$cycle
else
    mkdir $dir
    mv $file $dir
fi
  else
        echo "File error"
        echo $file
  fi
done
```

Comment: @jDo Thanks for the link. :)